# Correct use of 'warned' and 'apprised'

Tags: word-choice

What term would correctly complete this sentence:

> "The local official _ _ _ _ _ _ the Minister of the situation"
>
> 1. explained
> 2. warned
> 3. apprised
> 4. told

I am confused between "warned" and "apprised". Both seem right to me. Which one of these two is the answer and why?

Comment: **"apprised"** seems to be the correct word. he just informed him didn't he? **Warn** carries another meaning.

Comment: There could be "a" situation where the local official "warns" the Minister of it. "Apprised" sounds right to me but "warned" doesn't seem wrong either.

Comment: You _apprise_ someone **of** something, but you _warn_ someone **about** something. The difference is in the use of the appropriate preposition for the verb.

Comment: @SteveES That's not the case... you can say **"warn of"** - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/warn

Comment: @SovereignSun You're right, you can use "warn of", but you generally wouldn't in this context. Also "apprised ... of the situation" is an idiomatic phrase

Comment: I agree. That's idiomatic.

Comment: Because on a test where we have to pick "the most appropriate word," we have to go with the one that's more idiomatic. Dang these choose the best answer questions.

Comment: I think we need to know the entire scenario to make out which word suits the best. If the minister already knows of the situation and the local minister tells him that it can get worse, then he will warn him against it, and not apprise him of it. "Apprise" should be used only if the Minister does not know about the situation before the official tells him about it. Right @SteveES

Comment: @Cotton "Apprise" is roughly synonymous with "inform", so it could also be an update - telling the minister more about a situation they already know something about. It is perhaps more common to use it when raising a subject or issue the listener is unaware of, but it doesn't have to be used like this.

Comment: @Cotton The use of "warning" means that the speaker is informing about possible, or probable, negative consequences; i.e. providing a prediction of future action, not just information about a current situation. Because of this, you don't tend to warn "_of_ the situation", because that is something currently happening. You might warn "_about_ the situation", because it is warning of the _consequences_ of "the situation", or you might warn someone "of impending doom" because that is a future implication.

Comment: @SteveES: There's something in what you say, but we can obviously say something like "[...] warned X of Y's intentions", even though the intentions themselves constitute a present situation rather than a predicted negative future consequence. I have to say, this whole thing is pretty subtle . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on context.

'Warned' would be used if the 'situation' was dangerous or threatening. "Apprised" simply means to inform and does not imply the need for immediate action.

For instance, if the 'situation' was that a fire had broken out in the town, then it would be: "The local official *warned* the Minister of the situation".

However, if the 'situation' was that a general task had been completed, then it would be: "The local official *apprised* the Minister of the situation".